# SQL query for below operation

Tags: sql

```
Number | UserId | Priority
--------------------------
1234   | User1  | 1
2345   | User1  | 2
5678   | User1  | 3
2456   | User2  | 1
6556   | User2  | 2
2435   | User3  | 1
6567   | User3  | 2
```

I want to extract the below list of row based on the highest value of Priority

```
Number | UserId | Priority
--------------------------
5678   | User1  | 3
6556   | User2  | 2
6567   | User3  | 2
```

Considering the table name as usercode can someone help with the sql query for this.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: What sql engine you're using and do you want only top three rows with highest priority ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I want only the rows with high priority value of each UserId

Comment: Yes - but do you want exactly three rows with highest priority, or rows with priority higher than some number, or everything just sorted by priority ? If you want just highest priority, you shouldn't have two rows with priority = 2 in your question.

Comment: @fancyPants solution worked for me. as for your question i wanted to return row with maximum priority for each userid and the priroty value can be anything. in the table given above user1 has max priority value of 3 and user2 has max priority value of 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.number,A.userId,A.Priority from TableName A 
inner join
(
 Select UserId,Max(Priority) as Priority from  TableName group by UserId
) B on A.Priority =B.Priority  and A.UserId=B.UserId
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70099/6)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write it is

```
select
a.*
from
TableName a
left join TableName b
on a.Priority < b.Priority 
and a.UserId = b.UserId
where b.Priority is null
```

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when a.priority is at its maximum value, there is no b.priority with a greater value and the b rows values will be NULL.

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70099/7/0).

Comment: Thank you :) This works for me. But when executed on 67000 rows of data its taking me around 3 seconds to get a result of 5 rows. is there any way increase the performance ?

Comment: Have indexes on UserId and Priority and it should run in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Number, A.UserId, A.Priority 
FROM usercodeTBL A 
INNER JOIN(SELECT UserId, Max(Priority) AS Priority FROM usercodeTBL GROUP BY UserId) B 
ON A.Priority = B.Priority  AND A.UserId = B.UserId
ORDER BY UserId, Priority DESC
```